# Powershell, how to get desired columns from a file

Tags: powershell, file-io

In windows powershell
Input file data

`WL363998      google.com      172.217.166.46                                            32       7
WL363998      fb.com          157.240.16.35                                             32       7 
WL363998      bing.com        13.107.21.200                                             32       6`

Outfile which i needed

`google.com      172.217.166.46
fb.com          157.240.16.35 
bing.com        13.107.21.200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
(& {
    foreach ($line in Get-Content -Path .\data.txt)
    {
        $columns = $line -split '\s+'
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Domain = $columns[1]
            IP = $columns[2]
        }
    } 
} | Out-String).Trim() | Out-File -FilePath output.txt -NoNewline
```

**Explanation:**

- Read each line with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) into an array of strings.
- Split each line on all whitespace with `\s+`. Have a look at [`about_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) for more information.
- Insert 1st and 2nd columns into [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0).
- Pipe to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7), so we can [`Trim()`](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html) trailing whitespace.
- Pipe to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7) to create a new output file, making sure we don't include new lines with `-NoNewline`(optional).

**output.txt**

```
Domain     IP
------     --
google.com 172.217.166.46
fb.com     157.240.16.35
bing.com   13.107.21.200
```

Comment: Wow!!! great...its working fine as i expected. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Done as suggested :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat "Filepath" | %{$_.split("`t")[1,2] -join "`t"}
```

Comment: PS C:\Users\singhkaw> cat final.txt | %{$_.split("`t")[1,2] -join "`t"}


####################not getting anything as an output :-(

Comment: Isn't the fields tab separated?

Comment: actaully the data in file which i was getting that was from command output. But anyways thank you so much for your quick turn around